# How to mock local object creations in JUnit

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

I am not aware about how to mock local objects within a method using JUnit and mockito.

JDK - 1.7, JUnit - 4.12, powermock-module-junit4 - 1.6.6, powermock-api-mockito - 1.6.6

Also, bringing in the point that I must use only JDK 1.7.

In the below sample class, how do mock "service" object which is at method scope.

```
class A {
public String methodA() {

SampleService service = new SampleService();
return service.retrieveValue();

}
}
```

Please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't mock local variable. But you can do following:

1) Create a Factory and inject int o tested class. After that refactoring you could mock the factory and provide mocked service to tested object.

```
class A {
    private SampleServiceFactory factory;
    public String methodA() {
        SampleService service = factory.createSampleService();
        return service.retrieveValue();
    }
}
```

In test you should inject factory mock and after that return mock of the service on createSampleService() call:

```
when(mockFactory.retrieveValue()).thenReturn(mockService);
```

2) You can extract method and override it in the test and return mock instead of the implementation:

```
class A {
    public String methodA() {
        SampleService service = createSampleService();
        return service.retrieveValue();
    }

   protected SampleService createSampleService() {
     return new SampleService();
   }
}
```

In this approach you can do following:
@Test

```
public void testServiceCall() {
   A testedObject = new A() {
       @Override
       protected SampleService createSampleService() {
         return mockSampleService;
       }
   }
   ...
   testedObject.methodA();
   ...
   verify(service).retrieveValue();
}
```

**PS**: I would prefer first one, access modifier changing is not the best approach by my opinion.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. So, I understand that only via factory pattern, such objects can be injected in JUnit.

Comment: @sridhar For _service classes_, you should usually inject the actual service object directly instead of a factory.

Comment: Thank you for clarification! (i have just updated the answer)
And after mock factory injection `when(mockFactory..retrieveValue()).thenReturn(mockService)`

Answer (score 1):

You don't. You fix the method so that `SampleService` is injected either as a method parameter or as part of `A`'s constructor.